# How can I change Vim settings?

Tags: vim

First of all, I'm a total newbee, studying some code in order to go in a good programming school, but so far, let's say I don't know much about anything.

I'm currently using vim, but every time I launch it I have to write `:set nocompatible`, `:set backspace=indent,eol,start`, `:set nu` (I have quite a strict norm to follow) and `:syntax on`. I tried to search by myself how I could change Vim's settings in order to not have to write these every single time, but as I said, I'm new here and I don't understand most of the answers. So even though I guess you've already answered this kind of question somewhere else, I'd really need a bit of help if you may.

Thanks and sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Start here `:h vimrc`

Comment: Actually I would recommend `:help vimrc-intro`. :)

Answer (score 3):

Put all those commands in a .vimrc file in your home folder. It is a configuration file that vim loads everytime it starts.
:help is your friend if you don't understand what some commands you may find on the forums do.

Comment: It worked.

Okay so the issue was simple, I actually understood must of the thing I was told to do, but I got decieved by the fact that another _vimrc file already existed in vim's folder. I had to create another one in my home folder (as I was told by math). 

Thank you guys, it wasnt that hard but it really helped me out. 

See you around and thanks again.

Comment: @user3407061 You're welcome. But you should keep the old .vimrc file and append your options to it (save a backup before). It has some usefull options already enabled.

Comment: If you read `:help vimrc-intro` as @ebenezer suggested, then you know that the vimrc file is usually `_vimrc` on Windows and `.vimrc` on other systems.  Under `:help .vimrc` (several lines under `:help vimrc`, recommended by @Jeff) it says "Four places are searched for initializations.  The first that exists is used, the others are ignored."  So it is likely to cause confusion if you keep both a `.vimrc` and a `_vimrc` in your home directory.

Comment: Well there was no _vimrc file at all in my home folder, it in the vim folder (I had to dl vim later) but it didnt seem to affect anything. I kept the old folder and just created a new one in my home directory.